# Deploying Ruby on Rails App using Passenger & Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails application using Phusion Passenger and the Apache2 module on MacOS. I believe I have installed all dependencies and gems correctly and think a problem lies in my configuration files. I do not have a domain so I am trying to use localhost to deploy.

this first file is the configuration for the apache2 web server and is located in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I think my issue is with the `ServerName`. I do not have a domain to publicly host this web application from yet. I am trying to locally deploy it first. I have been using `localhost:3000` for my development and want to deploy it using that as well. Maybe I am not understanding something vital here with deploying and `ServerName`.

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost.depot
  DocumentRoot /Users/rubythree/Documents/agile-web-development-with-rails-5.1/production/depot/public
  SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE "secret_key_here"
  <Directory /Users/rubythree/Documents/agile-web-development-with-rails-5.1/production/depot/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the next file where an issue might be is the hosts file located in `/private/etc/hosts` where I added the following line...

hosts

```
127.1.1.1     localhost.depot
```

I am new to Phusion Passenger and Apache and am pretty sure I am missing something in my configuration files here. When i try to access the ip 127.1.1.1 after a while of loading the browser will not be able to reach the server. running `curl 127.1.1.1` will not return anything either, it will timeout. Any help or direction is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if `ServerName` does not match - apache will serve the first virtualhost as default.

"This machine" address is `127.0.0.1`, also make sure apache is actually running and has no errors in logs

Comment: hey gave this a try, changed the address to 127.0.0.1 and made sure there were no errors in the apache logs. Still the app would not display in the browser. maybe this issue is not in my configuration but somewhere else.